# Verify: The points of discontinuity of any $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ are a $F_\sigma$ set

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, continuity, proof-writing, baire-category

Prove that the points of discontinuity of an arbitrary function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ are a $F_\sigma$ set.

*Note: Proofs are available; this question is to verify and critique* this *proof and exposition.*

**Strategy:** At first, it seems that points of discontinuity admit no restrictions: they can have any cardinality $\leq |\mathbb R|$, and can be individual points or intervals, open, closed, both, or neither.

Our strategy therefore is to introduce a relaxed version of continuity, called *$\alpha$-continuous*, which admits only open intervals, and use it to successively approximate continuity.

**Definition:** A function $f: A \subseteq \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is *$\alpha$-continuous* at $x \in A$ if for a particular fixed $\alpha > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $y, z$ such that $|y - x|, |z - x| < \delta \implies |f(y) - f(z)| < \alpha$.

Note that this definition differs from standard continuity in that it compares the image of *two* points in the neighorhood of $x$, as opposed to of $x$ itself and *one* point in its neighborhood.  The reason for this change will become clear with the following lemma:

**Lemma 1:** For any $f: A \subseteq \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, for any $\alpha > 0$, the points where $f$ is $\alpha$-continuous form an open set.

Proof: By its definition, if $f$ is $\alpha$-continuous at $x$, then $f$ is $\alpha$-continuous at some open interval surrounding $x$.  The arbitrary union of open intervals is an open set.

Remark: As noted above, Lemma 1 is only true because we defined $\alpha$-continuous w.r.t any *two* points.

**Lemma 2:** For any $f: A \subseteq \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $f$ is continuous at $x \in A$ if and only if $f$ is $\alpha$-continuous at $x$ for all $\alpha > 0$.

Proof: If $f$ is continuous at $x$, then for any $\alpha > 0$, let $\varepsilon = \alpha/2$. All points in the $\delta$-neighborhood will then map within $(f(x) - \alpha/2, f(x) + \alpha/2)$ and thus be within $\alpha$ of each other, showing $f$ is $\alpha$-continuous at $x$.

Conversely, if $f$ is $\alpha$-continuous at $x$ for all $\alpha > 0$, then for any $\varepsilon > 0$, let $\alpha = \varepsilon$.  All points in the $\delta$-neighborhood will then be within $\varepsilon$ of $x$, showing $f$ is continuous at $x$.

**Main Proof:** Let $S_n = \{x \in A: f$ is not $\alpha$-continuous at $x$ for $\alpha = 1/n\}$.  By Lemma 1, $S_n$ is the complement of an open set and hence closed.  Let $S = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} S_n$.  Clearly, if $f$ is not $\alpha$-continous at $x$ for $\alpha = k$, it is not $\alpha$-continous at $x$ for $\alpha > k$, and so by Lemma 2, $S$ is precisely the set of points where $f$ is not continuous.  Since $S$ is a $F_\sigma$ set, the proof is complete.

**Remark:** We thus tame the uncountability of a set by building it via *successive approximations*, the analyst's tool of choice. Each approximation is a closed set, their union an illuminating example of $F_\sigma$.  Although our standard tools to tame infinite sets, namely countability and openness, both fail to directly apply to the points of discontinuity, successive approximations lets us introduce them nonetheless. *When dealing with an infinity too vast to contemplate, successively approximate it via something simpler.*

Open questions: Are there other ways to characterize the points of discontinuity, or is every $F_\sigma$ set admissable?  And are there questions that can be answered via successive approximations using uncountable collections of  $F_\sigma$ sets, taking this approach one meta level higher?

**Discussion:** Is the proof correct, rigorous, and well-written? How can it be improved? Are the remarks accurate and helpful? Any feedback, positive or negative, is appreciated.

Comment: Partial converse: If $X$ is a metric space with no isolated points (e.g. $X=\Bbb R$) and if $Y$ is an $F_{\sigma}$ subset of $X$ then there exists $f:X\to\Bbb R$ such that $Y$ is the set of discontinuities of $f$.

Comment: For more details about this converse, see Pete L. Clark and Dave L. Renfro's answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67620).

Comment: In response to  your response to my comment to the A by Anne Bauval: What part(s) do you have trouble with?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Are you recommending the same proof approach, but consolidating the steps, or a better approach? Which steps in the OP are extraneous? Which shortcuts did I miss?

Comment: Basically I gave the same proof, in a terser style. For great examples of "compact" style, see General Topology, by R. Engelking, or Set Theory: An Introduction To Independence Proofs, by K. Kunen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is the same as [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2869579) and is correct, rigorous, and well-written. See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138072) and many others, linked or related.

Your note after the definition of $\alpha$-continuity and your remark after lemma 1 are not convincing because if $\forall y,z\in V_\delta(x)\quad|f(y)-f(z)|<\alpha,$ then in particular $\forall y\in V_\delta(x)\quad|f(y)-f(x)|<\alpha,$ and conversely, if $\forall y\in V_\delta(x)\quad|f(y)-f(x)|<\alpha,$ then $\forall y,z\in V_\delta(x)\quad|f(y)-f(z)|<2\alpha$ (this is the *proof* your lemma 2). To me, the true "difference from standard continuity" is that it is an *intermediate notion* with $\alpha$ fixed, so that (for $f$ at $x$) standard continuity is equivalent to $\alpha$-continuity for all $\alpha>0$ (this is the *statement* of your lemma 2).

For me, the shorter the better but it is a matter of taste, so I will not propose an alternative shortened version of yours. Two minor improvements could be to replace "$\alpha$-continuous for $\alpha=1/n$" by "$1/n$-continuous" (and similarly with "$\alpha$-continuous for $\alpha=k$"), and to choose earlier a notation for the set of points where $f$ is (or is not) $\alpha$-continuous, so as to use it in your lemmas and main proof.

[The converse is true in $\Bbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67620), i.e. any $F_\sigma$ subset of $\Bbb R$ is the set of discontinuities of some function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R.$

Your theme is related to [Oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation_(mathematics)) and [Borel hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_hierarchy).

**Edit:** An important point which I did not notice before: The domain of your $f$ should not be $A\subset\Bbb R,$ but $\Bbb R$ itself. Or if you insist on keeping $f:A\to\Bbb R,$ the result will be an $F_\sigma$-subset *not of $\Bbb R$ but of $A$, equipped with the induced topology*.

Comment: I think we can streamline the proof : For $x\in \Bbb R$ and $q\in\Bbb Q^+,$ let  $x\in E(q)$ iff every nbhd of $x$ contains some $x',x''$ such that $|f(x')-f(x'')|\ge q.$ Prove $E(q)$ is closed. Now $f$ is discontinuous at $x$ iff $x\in E(q)$ for some $q\in\Bbb Q^+,$ i.e. iff $x\in\cup_{q\in\Bbb Q^+} E(q)$..... (Note: Either $x'$ or $x''$ might or might not be $x$.)

Comment: @DanielWainfleet
  Probably, but that was not the aim of this post, that is why I refrained from this. Moreover, this should not be a comment of my answer but of the post itself.

Comment: My comment was not meant as a criticism of your post.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I did not feel offended, I only understood it as a complement. On the other hand, *my* comment *was* a criticism of yours (please, don't take it bad): I don't think it was adequate nor at the right place.

Comment: Invaluable feedback.  Re "if ∀y ∈ Vδ(x) |f(y) − f(x) |<α, then... ∀y,z∈ Vδ(x) |f(y) − f(z) | < 2α" - while true, wouldn't that one point definition of $\alpha$-continuity allow isolated points? We'd have to use that if it $f$ is $k$-one-point-continuous at isolated point $x$, it is $2k$-one-point-continuous on an open interval - it's much simpler to build this into the definition.  I wasn't able to find a reference as to how this notion is typically defined: is there a standard definition for something similar to $\alpha$-continuous?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I don't entirely follow your suggestion.  Would you consider elaborating it into a full answer?

Comment: That definition of α-continuity would not "allow isolated points" more nor less than the other one. But I agree with your technical objection. My "criticism" was only about your note and remark. As for the reference, there is one in the second linked post: "exercise from Royden's 3rd edition", and the definition is yours. There are also [a lot of references here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/67996/386889) given by Dave L. Renfro.